# Finding the adjoint of operator on P_1

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, adjoint-operators

The question asks to find the adjoint of the operator T on P$_1$([0,1]), which is the space of polynomials with degree no greater than 1 over the field [0,1], which contains all numbers between 0 and 1, inclusive. Specifically, the operator T is defined as: $$p → \int_0^1 x^{k} p(x) dx$$
What I've tried so far is I tried solving T(f), where f ∈ P$_1$([0,1]), and then plugging it into the inner product on the space of functions, which is <f,g> = $\int_0^1 f(x) g(x) dx$, and calculating that with g, where g ∈ P$_1$([0,1]), but then that doesn't really give me anything, just a complicated constant and the integral of g(x). Someone else I asked suggested I try using the inner product immediately, without solving for T(f), but I'm not sure how that would help any more than what I already did.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance. I'm a first-year undergrad student by the way, if that affects any answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what that someone else was referring to was writing $\langle Tf,g\rangle$ as a double integral and using Fubini's theorem, but that doesn't actually give you an operator in $P_1[0,1]$.

Instead, we use what George outlined: if $ax+b$ corresponds to $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix}$, then we see that the inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle$ corresponds to the matrix
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{1}{2} & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Likewise, as George said,
$$T \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{a}{k+2} + \frac{b}{k+1}\end{pmatrix} \implies T = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ \frac{1}{k+2} & \frac{1}{k+1} \end{pmatrix}.$$

Now, suppose $$f = \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b\end{pmatrix},\quad  g = \begin{pmatrix} c\\d\end{pmatrix}.$$
In matrix notation, we need to find a matrix $S$ such that
$$(Tf)^T Pg = f^TP(Sg).$$
For this to hold true, we need $T^TP = PS,$ or $$S = P^{-1}T^TP.$$
For $P$ the identity matrix, this would mean $S = T^T$, but as $P$ isn't the identity matrix, we would need to take matrix inverses.

Answer (score 0):

According to the definition $T(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}(ax+b)dx=\dfrac{a}{k+2}+\dfrac{b}{k+1}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
 \dfrac{1}{k+2}&\dfrac{1}{k+1}  \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
 a\\b
\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $T^{\star}:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is

$T^{\star}(y)=\begin{bmatrix}
 \dfrac{1}{k+2}\\\dfrac{1}{k+1}
\end{bmatrix}y$

Comment: $T$ should be an operator from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, right? There should be a first row with 0's in the definition of $T$. Second, assuming your basis is $(1,x)$, this is not an orthonormal basis for the inner product so you're not simply taking the transpose, no?

Comment: As you have defined it $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ and hence $T^{\star}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$. Just use the definition and matrix algebra!

Comment: Can you glance at my answer and let me know if I'm making a mistake here? Our answers should be identical.

Comment: @GeorgeTsoutsinos The problem with your answer is that the matrix of $T^*$ is not always the transpose of the matrix of $T$. This is true when the basis you use is orthonormal though.

Comment: My friend is not as complicated as you think. You have a linear function $T(a,b)=\int_{0}^{1}x^{k}(ax+b)dx=\dfrac{a}{k+2}+\dfrac{b}{k+1}=
[\dfrac{1}{k+2} \dfrac{1}{k+1}]
\begin{bmatrix}
a \\b
\end{bmatrix}
$. You have $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ expressed in the matrix form [1x2][2x1] as in my answer. So the adjoint is just the transpose $T^{\star}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ of the form [2x1]y as I give in my answer. There is no need for inner products and orthonormal bases!

Comment: Forget functions and just think that $T$ is a $1x2$ matrix, So the adjoint is just the transpose of this matrix which is a $2x1$ matrix!

Comment: Since $T : P_1[0,1] \to P_1[0,1]$, why does the domain of the adjoint change? Isn't $y$ supposed to be a polynomial?

Comment: I tried to explain many times that the range of $T$ is not $P_{1}[0,1]$ but $\mathbb{R}$. Every polynomial of degree $n$ is identified with an element of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. It is just $(a_{n},a_{n-1},.....,a_{1},a_{0})$. So what you have got is $T:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\,\mathbb{R}$ and hence the adjoint (which is just the transpose) is $T^{\star}:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\,\mathbb{R}^{2}$ and if you want to write it in a polynomial form is $T^{\star}(\lambda)=\lambda(\dfrac{1}{k+2}x+\dfrac{1}{k+1})$